# Is it possible to programmatically query a database where DB tables relationships were added in the ADO.NET and not in the DB itself?

Tags: linq, ado.net, navigation-properties, table-relationships

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC3 with C# and Razor.

The application has to use an existing database, designed about 8 years ago where there is **no physical relationship** between tables. Other applications using the same DB create relationships programmatically by using joins.

In my application I created an **ADO.NET** model for some database's tables. Now in order to get advantage of the potentialities of **inline LINQ expressions**, especially the **navigation properties**, I would like to create relationships on the ADO.NET model.

Is ADO.NET powerful enough to translate inline expressions, where I make use of relationships, into queries understandable by the actual database where such relationships are not existing?

Comment: What do you mean there is no physical relationship between tables? Does that mean that there are no Foreign Keys defined? If so, you could still make JOIN statements.

Comment: exactly there are no foreign keys in the SQL database. I can make LINQ joins but I cannot use the navigation properties, those that allow you to jump from one table to another by simply using the dot notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationships in ADO.NET can be physical (having Foreign Keys constraints in the database) or logical (the relationship is defined only in the application).

You can add the relationships manually in the designer and they you will have navigation properties.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However it is not what I was looking for. I was wondering whether the queries are correctly executed by using LINQ if the foreign keys are present just in the ADO.NET model and not in the actual SQL database.

Comment: The LINQ expressions are transformed to SQL and the filtering is done on the server side. In other words, if you define relationships between tables, you will benefit the navigation properties you needed and the expressions are transformed correctly into SQL queries. Maybe this would help: "the existence of relationship properties is more important on the results side of a query than as part of the query itself". Checkout for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic11